# Can't call my #define variable

Tags: objective-c, c-preprocessor

I just started playing with `#define` option, so I defined some variables in a `global.h` file.

```
#define GOLFER_DATA_NAME  @"name"
#define GOLFER_DATA_UNION  @"union"
#define GOLFER_DATA_GENDER  @"gender"
#define GOLFER_DATA_JUNIOR  @"junior"
#define GOLFER_DATA_MEMNO  @"memno"
#define GOLFER_DATA_SEARCHMODE  @"SearchMode"
#define GOLFER_DATA_EMAIL  @"E-mail"
```

But I can't access `GOLFER_DATA_NAME` or `GOLFER_DATA_UNION` anywhere in my code. I'm sure that I missed something but what? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Did you `#import "global.h"`?

Comment: Yes worked, but it didn't auto recognise my global.h file? But i worked after compiling it

Comment: @user2408952 You **can't**? Why not, what error are you getting? Post the whole file and all relevant error messages!

Comment: Just don't understand why i need to call it, because i got another project where it works and I'm not calling #import "global.h" anywhere in my code. Anyway thanks this worked.

Comment: If you don't import it in some way into the current compilation unit, how is the compiler supposed to know about anything in the file? Note that you might have imported it in your precompiled header, or indirectly through another header that you pulled it, hard to tell with the information you provided. But your other project *did* pull in the header for you to be able to have used it.

Comment: Did you check that it wasn't imported in a the `YourApp-Prefix.pch` for example?

Comment: interesting it is imported in my YourApp-Prefix.pch. But both projects does this, and it only works in one of them?

Comment: @user2408952 Are you sure that your project uses the right precompiled header?

Comment: This is my PrempiledHeaders Cache Path: $(CACHE_ROOT)/SharedPrecompiledHeaders

Comment: You should put a lower-case `k` in front of all of those.

Comment: @user2408952 You can view it when you click on your project in Xcode and then scroll down a bit. The path is usually something like "MyApp/Supporting files/MyApp-Prefix.pch

Comment: @nhgrif That is totally up to him, personal preference and has nothing to do with the question... Wish I could downvote comments

Comment: That has nothing to do with your problem... but it is still something you should do.  For your actual problem, check my actual answer.

Comment: @JustSid There's a reason it's a comment and not part of my answer.

Comment: SWEET the "k" in front of my $(CACHE_ROOT)/SharedPrecompiledHeaders worked. BIG thanks. SO now I'm getting curious why do i need that "k"?

Comment: @nhgrif Great... Have fun explaining your comment now...

Comment: That's not where I was recommended the k... But it's probably working because something in my answer triggered

Answer (score -1):

If you're importing a file in your pre-compiled header file (`.pch`), you shouldn't need to re-import it in any other file in that project (though it doesn't hurt, and may help future readability).

Presuming Xcode, sometimes when you create a new file in your project, it may not quite sync up with the rest of the project immediately.  To fix this, you can try saving the file (Cmd+S), cleaning the project (Cmd+Shift+K), or building the project (Cmd+B).  After this, the imports should be working fine.

This is similar to when you've created a new file and can't import it into another or can't link to it from interface builder.  Usually just a quick Cmd+S save fixes the problem for me.